# Execute managedBean method only for a specific page

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

For a page, I need to initialize potentially a huge list of object.
For now, I populate this list in a @PostConstruct method

Is it possible to execute a method only on a specific page?

Or is there a JSF tag to simply execute a method and nothing more ?

It's not an important issue for me but there must be a solution.

I'm using JSF 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add this to your page:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{backingBean.desiredMethod()}" />
```

This will execute the `desiredMethod()` before the RenderView lifecycle phase.

Comment: I will but have to wait 4 minutes :)